# Global Navigation (Structural) Dropdown Arrows are only shown in Modern Experience

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, modern-experience, 2019, classic-experience

in Sharepoint 2019 On-Premise, the root web of a site collection has the settings:

"Navigation"->"Global Navigation"->"Structural Naviation: Display the navigation items below the current site" with "Show subsites" checked, and "maximum number of dynamic items" set to 100.

Subsites of the root web are:

```
Site1
  Site1.1
  Site1.2
Site2
```

When viewing any page in Modern Experience, the Global Navigation is shown with a dropdown arrow:

```
Site1⌄ Site2
```

However, in Classic Experience, the links are shown without hierarchy, flatly next to each other, beginning with a link to the /SitePages/Home.aspx of the root web:

```
LinkToRootWebHome Site1 Site1.1 Site1.2 Site2
```

Is there some setting that must be enabled specifically for Classic Experience?

Comment: I have the opposite experience. Hierarchy is only shown on Classic pages, but Modern ones are flat, with subsites left out completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SharePoint classic experience, by design, structural navigation shows as LinkToRootWebHome Site1 Site1.1 Site1.2 Site2